# Save to OneDrive from ERP

Tags: erp, onedrive

We want to save documents to individual OneDrive Folders.

Currently:
User "Tim" generates a customer overview (Last visits, Revenue etc.) in our ERP-Sytem from Customer "TomCompany" and it will be automatically saved in an FTP-Folder. He's now able to have a look on this file at customers site with Good Reader on his iPad.

Plan:
First step: The customer overview should be saved directly to OneDrive, instead of an FTP-Folder.
Second step: Every Sales Person has his own OneDrive account, so it should be saved to his own account with user-Parameters etc. (which is not a Problem to manage in our ERP-API).

The question is: Is it possible to connect to OneDrive from a different System like ERP. "SaveFileToOneDrive with Authentication"

Comment: What are you asking for? Sounds like a job offer :-D

Comment: True :)
The question is: Is it possible to connect to OneDrive from a different System like ERP. "SaveFileToOneDrive with Authentication"

Answer (score 0):

You can 'connect' to OneDrive through the given API with JavaScript.

Here is an example: https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-save.htm .
You can now add the 'Save to OneDrive' button on every page you need it.

If not noticed yet, some examples for the API: https://dev.onedrive.com/sample-code.htm

Hope this helps you to solve your (for me still unknown) problem ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to add it in our System.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented own windows live API because of I found some problems with standard live api. It is based on REST API so there is layer with objects (file, folder, etc...) and each object has some equipment (i.e. file has method for upload and download file). Second layer is for communication with server side and object layer send requests into second layer which send it into server. Server sends response and second layer return this response into object layer. 
I implemented onedrive function mainly because of I developed application which uploads some files into onedrive.

So it is very simple to use it. I describe it on webpage https://wlivefw.codeplex.com/
You can sign as user which onedrive want to use by connection object. Then you will need folder id where you want to create new file. Then you create file object with parent_id set to folder id, name (is required) and description (optional). And now you call File.Create(file object which you created, Stream object - data of origin file, OverWriteOption - if you want to overwrite file if exists or not or create with new name, and progress handler - delegate to method which you want to invoke when progress changed).

File uploading is implemented by BITS protocol, so you can upload file greater than 60MB. File is uploaded by fragment so if fragment uploading fails you can very easy send this fragment again - in exception when uploading fails is delegate to continue method which continue upload from last successfull fragment.

I would like to improve this library so library is free to use as well as source code. Please if you will expand this library send me your changes and I will build new version, etc... Thank you and I hope it is usefull.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Zefek.
I'll forward it to our expert developers and come back to you, hopefully soon.